# Copy an image to another location with different size

Tags: java, file-io, file-copying

I am trying to copy an image file from one location to another using Java. Now I want to save the image file for a specific size whatever is the size of image file in source location.

I am using the following code, it is producing the image on the destination location with the same size as source file:

```
public class filecopy {
    public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile)
            throws IOException {
        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();

            // previous code: destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
            // to avoid infinite loops, should be:
            long count = 0;
            long size = source.size();
            while ((count += destination.transferFrom(source, count, size
                    - count)) < size)
                ;
        } finally {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       try {
        File sourceFile = new File("D:/new folder/abc.jpg");
        File destFile = new File("d:/new folder1/abc.jpg");
        copyFile(sourceFile,destFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice project, I always wanted to do that myself too. What is your question however?

Comment: FYI, your code is not compilable (you have some dangling strings at the end).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code for resizing the image as per your specification.
Inside the copyFile method,

```
int width=100,height=75; /* set the width and height here */
BufferedImage inputImage=ImageIO.read(sourceFile);
BufferedImage outputImage=new BufferedImage(width, height,
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g=outputImage.createGraphics();
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
g.drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(outputImage,"jpg",destFile);
/* first parameter is the object of the BufferedImage,
   second parameter is the type of image that you are going to write,
       you can use jpg, bmp, png etc
   third parameter is the destination file object. */
```

Comment: i want to resize the file suggest me with example after compiling my given code.

Comment: @adeshsingh import relevant packages too. hope this is what you need.